# Check if variable in classic asp array

Tags: arrays, variables, asp-classic

I'm trying to  check if the value of a variable is in an array. Having some difficulty. My array is stored it the global.asa.

```
    Dim aTree(5)
   aTree(0) = "a"
    aTree(1) = "b"
    aTree(2) = "c"
    aTree(3) = "d"
    aTree(4) = "e"
    aTree(5) = "f"
       Application("aTree") = aTree
```

The variable I'm trying to check stores some html content

```
<% If tree = "a" Then %>
     <div class="card bg_white">
            <h1 class="bold small-caps tbrown">my content</h1>
    </div>
<% End If %>
```

I'm trying to do the check this way

```
<% tree = Request("tree") 
if in_array(tree, aTree) then %>
You've found it
<% End if %>
```

I've got this clunky version that works

```
(tree <> "" and tree <> "a" and tree <> "b" and tree <> "c" and tree <> "d" and tree <> "e" and tree <> "f")
```

But I'd like a more elegant way of doing it with an array.

Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

There's no built-in `InArray()` function, but it should be simple enough to build your own.

```
Function InArray(theArray,theValue)
    dim i, fnd
    fnd = False
    For i = 0 to UBound(theArray)
        If theArray(i) = theValue Then
            fnd = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    InArray = fnd
End Function
```

Modifying this function to return the index of the value instead of just true/false is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: Liked the "exercise" 

Comment: @TheCuBeMan: :) Of course, I used to *hate* it when my math textbooks did that sort of thing.

Comment: well, that's the best way to learn (and remember!), eventually ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is much faster (as it doesn't potentially loop through the whole array) and elegant. It uses the Filter function:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_filter.asp

```
function arrayIncludes(byval arr, byval value, byval matchCase)

    dim a, compareType

    arrayIncludes = false

    if (matchCase = false) then 
        compareType = 1
        value = lcase(value)
    else
        compareType = 0
    end if

    myFilter = Filter(arr, value, true, compareType)

    for a = 0 to ubound(myFilter)
        if (matchCase = false) then 
            myFilter(a) = lcase(myFilter(a))
        end if

        if (myFilter(a) = value) then 
            arrayIncludes = true
            exit for
        end if
    next

end function
```

Usage (returns true if element is in array, or false if it is not):

```
isIncluded = arrayIncludes(arrayToCheck, elementToSearch, true)  ' or false for matching case
```